# How to get mathematica online to operate at a normal speed?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematica-online

I have a nice notebook related to the world cup.  It works great and fast enough on my desktop machine.

However, when I try to run it using Mathematica Online, it is painfully slow to the point where it wont even initialize.  On the desktop, it runs flawlessly after about five seconds.  Trying to run using Mathematica Online often fails after trying to initialize after more than 30 minutes.

The code is linked below.

Questions:
1) I'm sure that my code is not efficient but still it should run using Mathematica Online - shouldn't it?

2) If mathematica runs the code on a server, it should only have to send over the graphics to the client side.  Why is it so slow?  Or, if the code runs on the client side, it should run as fast as my desktop version.  So, why is it so slow?  Or, if it is a combination - one would think it is optimized to be as fast as possible.  So why is it so slow?

3) Is anybody actually doing something useful using Mathematica Online? Every single notebook I upload, even very simple ones, runs slowly and usually makes a mess of the user interface (controls in the Manipulate command).

4) People say that my world cup notebook is very cool - can anybody help me make it run online so that others can enjoy it?

Here's the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7AGWaUYd7j3xT0St7p5VUxrQd-LBPzE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The Cloud can be used effectively, but it still can’t compete with a standard notebook for speed. Unfortunately I don’t think one can reasonably expect the cloud notebooks to work exactly as desktop notebooks do. Rather it should be treated as somewhere in between a notebook and static website, I find.